# dynamic header change per post option in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

Hi I need to set dynamic header so i can set banner/header with custom button with link per post ? is there any plugin or coding option ? can I create theme option with [ACF](https://advancedcustomfields.com) for it. sample design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo132.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "dynamic" header, what do you mean by dynamic? What criteria/logic will decide what header will display?

You can create different page templates and link different headers in the page template? That would be the easiest.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/